# Trying to run a Python Script from the terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Following the book 'Automate the boring stuff with Python' I wrote a Python script called mclip.py.

```
#! python3
# mclip.py - A multi-clipboard program.

TEXT = {'agree': """Yes, I agree. That sounds fine to me.""",
'busy': """Sorry, can we do this later this week or next week?""", 'upsell': """Would you consider making this a monthly donation?"""}

import sys, pyperclip 

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('Usage: py mclip.py [keyphrase] - copy phrase text') 
    sys.exit()

keyphrase = sys.argv[1] # first command line arg is the keyphrase

if keyphrase in TEXT:
    pyperclip.copy(TEXT[keyphrase])
    print('Text for ' + keyphrase + ' copied to clipboard.')
else:
    print('There is no text for ' + keyphrase)
```

When I run this in visual studio code I get:

```
XXX@XXXs-MacBook-Pro Python Projects % /usr/local/bin/python3 "/Users/XXX/Desktop/Python Projects/mclip.py"
Usage: py mclip.py [keyphrase] - copy phrase text
```

But following the instructions of the book when trying to run the script from the terminal typing `python3 mclip.py $busy` I get:

```
XXX@XXXs-MacBook-Pro ~ % python3 mclip.py 
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'mclip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

It should copy the value of the specific keyword but is not doing so. I am not sure what is causing this problem. Help is much appreciated!

Maybe there could be a problem with the Path VSC is set up with but I am not sure.

Comment: Is this a question about how to run a script in python, or how your script behaves once it is running?

Comment: I try to run a script from the terminal. But it is not working as it should. Running the script from VSC is not working as it should as well.

Comment: Can you explain the difference in the output you are seeing?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. I posted the output in the description of my question (If I run it directly from VSC or the terminal).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the Problem by myself and wanted to say here that no one has to bother finding a solution for me or in case my solution may be helpful for other people around here. My Mistakes were:

1. Trying to run the program without an argument. When calling the program I need 
   to call it with an argument: `python3 mclip.py busy`
2. Saving my scripts in an iCloud folder. Apparently it needs to be saved local.

These are all the changes I made and now it's running smoothly.

Thanks for the help anyone.